# graphql/apollo persistent queries are too long(http 414)

Tags: wordpress, nginx, next.js, graphql

I'm currently working on a site wgich has a frontend consisting of next.js which communicates over graphql to a WordPress backend. the persistent queries are generated(by graphql-codegen) and are saved to a .json files both the backend and frontend can access these files.

here is the code relating to apollo and apollo codegen

codegen.js

```
const environment = process.env.ENV || 'development';
const url = require(`./config/${environment}`);

module.exports = {
  schema: `${url.backend}/graphql`,
  documents: ['./lib/queries/fragments/*.js', './lib/queries/*.js'],
  generates: {
    './lib/persisted-query-ids/client.json': [
      {
        'graphql-codegen-persisted-query-ids': {
          output: 'client',
          algorithm: 'sha256',
          preset: 'near-operation-file',
        },
      },
    ],
    './lib/persisted-query-ids/server.json': [
      {
        'graphql-codegen-persisted-query-ids': {
          output: 'server',
          algorithm: 'sha256',
          preset: 'near-operation-file',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

[image]

createApolloClient.js

```
export default function createApolloClient(initialState, ctx) {
  const hashes = require('../../persisted-query-ids/client.json');

  const persistedLink = createPersistedQueryLink({
    useGETForHashedQueries: true, // Optional but allows better caching
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
    generateHash: usePregeneratedHashes(hashes),
  });

  // The `ctx` (NextPageContext) will only be present on the server.
  // use it to extract auth headers (ctx.req) or similar.

  const fetchOptions = {
    // credentials: 'include',
    redirect: 'manual',
  };

  const fetchWithCookies = async (input, init) => {
    let isomorphicFetch;
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
      isomorphicFetch = (await import('isomorphic-unfetch')).default;
    } else {
      isomorphicFetch = window.fetch;
    }
    const result = await isomorphicFetch(input, init);
    if (ctx?.res) {
      const cookiesFromApi = result.headers.get('set-cookie');
      if (cookiesFromApi) {
        ctx?.res.setHeader('set-cookie', cookiesFromApi);
      }
    }

    return result;
  };

  const cookieLink = createCookieLink(ctx);

  const httpLink = persistedLink.concat(
    new HttpLink({
      uri: `${config.wordpress.backend}/graphql`,
      fetchOptions,
      fetch: fetchWithCookies,
      useGETForQueries: true,
    })
  );

  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
    link: cookieLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || {}),
  });
}
```

this is the URL of the request, as you can see its quite big. the problem is apollo wants to use the query and not the persisted query id. this request causes a http 414 code. one of the fixes is to make another query for the fragments

```
https://example.com/wp/graphql?query=query%20GetFrontPage%20%7B%0A%20%20page%3A%20pageOnFront%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...PageData%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afragment%20PageData%20on%20Page%20%7B%0A%20%20title%0A%20%20content%0A%20%20link%0A%20%20excerpt%0A%20%20pageTemplate%0A%20%20hero%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20heroColor%0A%20%20%20%20heroImage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20sourceUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20altText%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20heroTitle%0A%20%20%20%20heroTitleTop%0A%20%20%20%20heroDescription%0A%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20featuredImage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...FeaturedImage%0A%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20seo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...Seo%0A%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20...FlexContentPage%0A%20%20__typename%0A%7D%0A%0Afragment%20Seo%20on%20PostTypeSEO%20%7B%0A%20%20title%0A%20%20metaDesc%0A%20%20metaKeywords%0A%20%20metaRobotsNofollow%0A%20%20metaRobotsNoindex%0A%20%20canonical%0A%20%20opengraphTitle%0A%20%20opengraphDescription%0A%20%20opengraphImage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20sourceUrl(size%3A%20FEATIMGSOCIAL)%0A%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20twitterTitle%0A%20%20twitterDescription%0A%20%20twitterImage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20sourceUrl(size%3A%20FEATIMGSOCIAL)%0A%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20__typename%0A%7D%0A%0Afragment%20FlexContentPage%20on%20Page%20%7B%0A%20%20flexContent%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20flexiblecontent%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Page_Flexcontent_Flexiblecontent_SellingPoints%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20subtitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sellingpointsBackgroundColor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cta%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20listTitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pointsList%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20point%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Page_Flexcontent_Flexiblecontent_Titlelayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20titleBackgroundcolor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20titles%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20titleTitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20titleTitleColor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Page_Flexcontent_Flexiblecontent_Testemonial%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20testemonial%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20facts%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20factCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20factTitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Page_Flexcontent_Flexiblecontent_Pointslayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20points%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20itemdescription%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20itemtitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Page_Flexcontent_Flexiblecontent_Bloglayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20blogSubtitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20blogCta%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20blogCases%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Post%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20uri%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20details%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20broad%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sourceUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20altText%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20customer%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20normal%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sourceUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20altText%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20small%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sourceUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20altText%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20subtitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20video%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mediaItemUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20altText%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20slug%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20featuredImage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sourceUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20altText%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20blogTitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20blogColor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20blogSubtitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Page_Flexcontent_Flexiblecontent_Latestlayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20latestTitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Page_Flexcontent_Flexiblecontent_Testlayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20testTitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Page_Flexcontent_Flexiblecontent_Textlayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wysiwyg%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20backgroundcolor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Page_Flexcontent_Flexiblecontent_Gallerylayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20photos%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pullup%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20photo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sourceUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20altText%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Page_Flexcontent_Flexiblecontent_Visuallayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20image%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sourceUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20altText%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Page_Flexcontent_Flexiblecontent_Customerslayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20subtitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20customers%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20link%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20logo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sourceUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20altText%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Page_Flexcontent_Flexiblecontent_Slidelayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ctaLink%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20slideBigTitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20slideBigDescription%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20slideContent%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20slideImage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sourceUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20altText%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20slideColor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20slideTitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20slideDescription%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Page_Flexcontent_Flexiblecontent_Teamlayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20teamContent%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20teamMemberName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20teamMemberRole%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20teamBigTitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20teamBigSubtitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20teamContent%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20teamMemberName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20teamMemberRole%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20teamMemberImage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sourceUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20altText%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Page_Flexcontent_Flexiblecontent_Awardslayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20awardsTitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20awardsBackgroundColor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20awardsSubtitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20awards%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20awardLink%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20awardLogo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sourceUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20altText%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20awardImage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sourceUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20altText%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20awardPrize%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20awardProject%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20awardOrganisation%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Page_Flexcontent_Flexiblecontent_Accordionlayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20accordionBackgroundColor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20accordionItems%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20accordionTitle%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20accordionContent%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20accordionServices%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20accordionService%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20__typename%0A%7D%0A%0Afragment%20FeaturedImage%20on%20NodeWithFeaturedImageToMediaItemConnectionEdge%20%7B%0A%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20link%0A%20%20%20%20sourceUrl(size%3A%20FEATIMGSOCIAL)%0A%20%20%20%20altText%0A%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20mediaDetails%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20width%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20height%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20__typename%0A%7D&operationName=GetFrontPage&variables=%7B%7D&extensions=%7B%22persistedQuery%22%3A%7B%22version%22%3A1%2C%22sha256Hash%22%3A%22e429ca4a5a03ff00fd8e895c639f032e66a3b212ced449b733d8a38693458419%22%7D%7D
```

What I want is that apollo automatically uses queryId as [seen on](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/performance/apq/#command-line-testing/) but I just can't figure out what could lead to a solution. if you have any suggestions I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the only solution is to split up the query into multible parts